# Case doesn't match as expected

Tags: json, playframework, websocket, akka

I've tried to implement a actor reacting to WebSocket messages in my application and I begun by trying code from the [Anonymou Chat demo application](https://github.com/anhminh1981/anonymous_chat).

```
// UserActor.scala 
def receive = LoggingReceive {
  case Message(muid, s) if sender == board =>
    val js = Json.obj("type" -> "message", "uid" -> muid, "msg" -> s)
    out ! js
  case js: JsValue =>
    (js \ "msg").validate[String] map { Utility.escape(_) } foreach { board ! Message(uid, _ ) }
  case other =>
    log.error("unhandled: " + other)
}
```

The problem is that when I send a message, it ends up in the `other` case.

```
[ERROR] [...] [...] [...] unhandled: {"msg":"user-moved"}
```

Instead it should be handled as `JsValue`. When I run the original sample application, it works even though it's the same code.

There's another difference I noticed that may reveal where the problem lies. This code (from the sample above):

```
case Message(muid, s) if sender == board =>
  val js = Json.obj("type" -> "message", "uid" -> muid, "msg" -> s)
  out ! js
```

Works in the sample application, but doesn't work in my application. To make it work in my application, I have to make `js` a string:

```
case Message(muid, s) if sender == board =>
  val js = Json.obj("type" -> "message", "uid" -> muid, "msg" -> s)
  out ! js.toString
```

I'm using Play 2.3.8 and sbt 0.13.
UserActor.scala: https://github.com/anhminh1981/anonymous_chat/blob/master/app/actors/UserActor.scala

Comment: How are you sending the message?

Comment: Via the original code of the Anonymous Chat example. This is a bit edited, but it should be equivalent: http://i.imgur.com/wKmqlg1.png

Comment: There might be implicit conversion in scope

Comment: @SKarthik I thought about it, but the imports are the same as well as the code. I've added a link to the UserActor.scala file to the question.

Comment: try log.error("unhandled: " + other + ", type:" + other.getClass ) . This might give a clue

Comment: Thank you @Rhaul and m-z. I've returned to this while cleaning my code and your comments made me realize that the problem was in the controller - using WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[String, String].